# Rails - Partial in another view can't access its controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a profile page that displays posts sent only to the requested user, and allows the visitor to write a post of their own. Because this simplified example should have two distinct controllers: users and posts, I made partials for each post action to render within the user's show action.

Directory structure for my views directory looks like this:

```
- posts
  - _index.html.erb
  - _new.html.erb

- users
  - show.html.erb
  ... (etc.)
```

Section that displays these partials within the user's `show.html.erb`:

```
<section>
    <h3>Posts:</h3>
    <%= render '/posts/new', :post => Post.new %>
    <%= render '/posts/index', :posts => Post.where(target_id: params[:id]) %>
</section>
```

I eventually found out that you could pass variables into the partial in this `render` line, and though this works, it's very messy and probably doesn't follow the best practices.

Ideally, I'd want these partials to be connected with the posts controller so I can write more complex database queries in a place that isn't the view:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def index
    @posts = Post.where(target_id: params[:id])
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)   
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    @post.target_id = params[:post][:target_id]

    if @post.save
        redirect_to :back, notice: 'You published a post!'
    else
        render new
    end
end

private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

Currently, I haven't found a way of doing this. I know this is a newb question, but thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to treat your controllers like models: doing the post work in post controller and the user work in user controller. But controllers are task-oriented, not model-oriented.

Since you want posts info in your user form, it's typical to gather it in the user controller. E.g.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    ...
    @posts = Post.where(user_id: user.id)
  end
end
```

That `@posts` instance variable is visible in the show template and any partials it calls. But many coders prefer to send it explicitly through `render` arguments, as more functional:

```
<%= render '/posts/post_list', posts: @posts %>
```

For one thing it's easier to refactor when you can see at a glance all of the partial's dependencies.

Comment: Huh, how curious, I didn't know controllers could be treated like that... Thanks for your help, Mori!

Answer (score 0):

I agree somewhat with @Mori's advice. As he said, you are trying to put too much logic into the controller. I think this was a result of you trying to get it out of the view, which is the right idea, but you want business logic to be in the model.

Also, those `index` and `new` actions for `PostsController` are never going to be called. When you are calling the render `posts/new` for example, that is rendering the view, not the controller action. So, those controller actions have no reason to exist.

I would implement the fix in perhaps a different way than Mori described. It's a recommended practice to try and pass as few instance variables from the controller to the view as possible ([see 3rd bullet in the linked section](https://github.com/thoughtbot/guides/tree/master/best-practices#rails)).

Since it's really the `show` action of the `UsersController` we are talking about here, I as someone trying to understand your code would assume the instance variable you are passing to the `show` view is something like `@user`.

You may want to use an `includes` method when instantiating the `@user` object. The `includes` statement will allow you to load the additional models you will need to instantiate using the minimum number of queries possible (preventing an N+1 query situation). You probably don't want to load every single one if there are thousands of matching posts, so I put an arbitrary limit of 10 on that.

**UsersController**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id]).includes(:received_posts).limit(10)
end

#....
```

**View**

```
<section>
    <h3>Posts:</h3>
    <% unless @user.id == current_user.id %>
      <%= render 'posts/form', post: Post.new(user_id: @user.id) %>
    <% end %>
    <%= render @user.received_posts %>
</section>
```

Putting the partial for a new `post` instead as a view called `posts/form` will allow you to reuse that form if you want to render an edit action (`form_for` knows which action to use on submit by calling the passed model's `persisted?` method).

Note that this code assumes the `User` model has the second relationship with posts set up to be called `received_posts`, but you can change it to whatever reflects the reality. By passing the `received_posts` collection to the render method, Rails is smart enough to know that if you want to render a collection of `Post` models to look for a `posts/_post` partial and render one for each `Post`. It's a little cleaner looking IMO. Just make sure to move your `posts/show` code into that. `posts/show` implies this is its own action and not something used as a partial for something else.